# Getting the value of json object in the frontend

Tags: python, django-templates, django-views

I am sending a template as well as a json object as render in django views

views.py

```
 def view(request):
 return render(request, "projectboard/about.html", {'name':"daredevil"})
```

How do I display this json object in the front end?

about.html

```
 <div ui-view>
 <div class="container">
 <h1><center>The about Page</center></h1>

 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
data_from_django = {{ my_data }}
 widget.init(data_from_django);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def view(request):
    data = {"name":"daredevil"}
    return render(request, "projectboard/about.html", {'my_data':data})
```

here `data` is context which is passed to the html page

In html page, access `data` with its `key` i.e. here "mydata"

```
     <div ui-view>
 <div class="container">
 <h1><center>The about Page</center></h1>

 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
data_from_django = {{ my_data }}
 widget.init(data_from_django);
 </script>
```

Comment: I got a message saying                                                                    "data_from_django is not defined"

Comment: can you display {{ my_data }} outside the script

Comment: can you do like `<p> {{ my_data }} </p>` before the js script what does it show

Comment: If you have named the correct html page and path, I dont see any issue with this code.

Comment: I think the variable `data_from_django` should be defined as `var data_from_django = {{ my_data }}` in javascript, check if it helps .

Answer (score 0):

Try changing that line to:

```
var data_from_django = '{{ name|escapejs }}';
```

The [escapejs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs) properly escapes the value for a JavaScript string context.

Comment: I got a message saying                                                                        "data_from_django is not defined"

Comment: Was the error in the browser console? Or coming from the Django error screen? Can you verify the HTML produced looks like: `data_from_django = '{\'name\':\"daredevil\"}';`?

Comment: Yes. It was in the browser console.                                                 Uncaught ReferenceError: data_from_django is not defined
    at <anonymous>:5:15
    at p (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Ia (jquery.min.js:3)
    at r.fn.init.after (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.enter (angular.js:3970)
    at Object.enter (angular-ui-router.min.js:7)
    at q (angular-ui-router.min.js:7)
    at A (angular-ui-router.min.js:7)
    at Scope.$broadcast (angular.js:12329)
    at t.transition.N.then.t.transition.t.transition (angular-ui-router.min.js:7)